# Alternative to inline scripting in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am aware that in-line scripting should be avoided by keeping html/css and javascript separated.

How is it possible to do such a thing in the following code?
//consider above in the code the function `alertMe()` declared

```
<img src="LittleBrain.png"  id="littlebrain" onClick="alertMe();">
```

How would it be possible not using in line code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener):

```
var img = document.getElementById('littlebrain');
img.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  alertMe();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('littlebrain').onclick = function() { alertMe(); }
```

or even shorter:

```
document.getElementById('littlebrain').onclick = alertMe;
```

Answer (score 2):

In a JavaScript code file, you can find the `img` element by its `id`, and then you can set its `onclick` handler. For example, using jQuery:

```
$("#littlebrain").click(function () {
  // ...handler code here...
});
```

In your case, the handler is a named function, called `alertMe`:

```
$("#littlebrain").click(alertMe);
```

Comment: alertMe is already a function, so this can be shortened to $("#littlebrain").click(alertMe);

Comment: @DavidHammond Thanks David, I refined my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the browsers you have to support, but if you're lucky and only get to worry about modern browsers, you can use `.addEventListener()`

```
var thing = document.getElementById('thing');

thing.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // do something here!
}, false);
```

If you're not so lucky, then you'll have to come up with a cross browser solution..

```
var thing = document.getElementById('thing');

addEvent(thing, 'click', function() {
  // do something
});

function addEvent(elem, event, callback) {
  if (elem.addEventListener) {
    elem.addEventListener(event, callback, false);
  } else if (elem.attachEvent) { // IE7 and earlier
    elem.attachEvent('on' + event, function() {
      callback.apply(elem, arguments);
    });
  } else {
    elem['on' + event] = callback;
  }
}
```

Or, if you use a library like jQuery, you can easily normalize the whole process

```
$('#thing').on('click', function() {
  // do something...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var el = document.getElementById('littlebrain');
el.addEventListener('click', alertMe, false);
```